# Get files from 1 directory and read files in another, than match files with file contents

Tags: php, arrays, file, directory, readdir

To explain what I mean, I have 1 directory containing images. I have another containing text files with information about the images. I want an array with each image matched with another array containing its data.

My head is beginning to explode trying to solve this, and my knowledge of PHP (especially arrays) is pretty small. If somebody could help fix what I've got so far, and perhaps help explain what's going on (or point me to a site which explains), I'd very much appreciate that.

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

function loadImages()
{
  $images=array();

  if ($handle = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery')) {

     $imageData = loadImageData();

      $count = 0;
      while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

          if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
              if((end(explode(".", $entry)) == "jpg") || (end(explode(".", $entry)) == "jpeg") || (end(explode(".", $entry)) == "JPG") || (end(explode(".", $entry)) == "gif") || (end(explode(".", $entry)) == "png")) {
                $images[$imagedata[$count]] = $entry;
                $count += 1;
              }
          }
      }

  }
        var_dump($images);

      closedir($handle);
      return $images;
}

function loadImageData()
{
  $imageData=array();

  if ($handle = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/data/')) {

      $count = 0;
      while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

          if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
              if(end(explode(".", $entry)) == "txt") {
                $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/data/';

                $file = fopen($path.$entry, "r") or die("Something went wrong gathering photo information. I suggest you contact the server admin about this.");
                $fileData = array();

                $line = 0;
                while(! feof($file)) {
                  $lineData = fgets($file);

                  $lineData = str_replace("\n", "", $lineData);
                  $lineData = str_replace("\r", "", $lineData);

                  $fileData[$line] = $lineData;
                  $line++;
                }

                fclose($file);

                $imageData[$count] = $fileData;
                $count += 1;
              }
          }
      }
  }

  closedir($handle);
  return $imageData;
}
?>
```

Comment: do the filenames correlate - ie img1.jpg and img1.txt?

Comment: @RamRaider Yes they do, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a slightly different approach based on the fact that the text file is named the same as the image.

Edited original code by encapsulating code within a function, so now you can call the function and process it's return value.

```
    function get_gallery_images(){

        /*

        */
        $imgdir=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery';
        $extns=array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');
        $output=array();



        /*
            Could have done this without the recursive iterators but... 
        */
        foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $imgdir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST ) as $file => $info ) {
            if( $info->isFile() ){

                $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
                $name=pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME );

                /* Only get images that have correct extension */
                if( in_array( $ext, $extns ) ) {

                    /* As data and image have the same name - we can deduce a filename */
                    $textfile=$imgdir . '/data/' . $name . '.txt';

                    /* Get image properties */
                    list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( $file );

                    /* If the text file does exist, add this image and associated data & properties to the output array */
                    if( file_exists( $textfile ) ){
                        clearstatcache();
                        $output[ $name ]=array( 'path' => $info->getPath(), 'data'=>file_get_contents( $textfile ), 'width'=>$width, 'height'=>$height, 'size'=>filesize( $file ) );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /* Process the output array in whatever whay you see fit */
        return $output;
    }


    /* Call the function */
    $output = call_user_func( 'get_gallery_images' );

    if( !empty( $output ) ){
        /* do whatever processing you require */
        foreach( $output as $key => $arr ){
            echo $key.' '.$arr['data'].'<br />';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works fine and really easy to see what's going on, thanks.

Comment: Good - glad it helped. You can do away with the getimagesize() and filesize() calls to make this faster

Comment: I was just looking at those and wondering why they were there. I will do that, thanks.

Comment: returning `$output` to another php file is simply returning an empty array. Any idea?

Comment: How do you mean? Are you trying to process the $output array using a different script or something?

Comment: your program is in a function in a separate PHP file, and when I call the function, `$output` is returned  to my main PHP file empty.

Comment: I hope I understood you correctly - I have now edited the above to make it into a function which you would call on your gallery page (for example)

Comment: I'm going to sound like a massive idiot. The reason my code appeared to be returning nothing was because I was using `echo` instead of `print_r`. Also it doesn't like your parameters for the printing `foreach`. Other than that everything is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Step-by-step solution:

1. You need to get the images from the folder where you have the images:

`$temporaryImageArray = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/');`

2. You need to get the text files from the folder where you have the text files:

`$temporaryTextArray = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery`/data/');

3. Both temporary arrays might hold unnecessary elements, such as subdirectories. For instance, your image folder contains the data subdirectory, which is unhelpful. So you need to prepare the useful subset of the image array:

`$images = array();
foreach ($temporaryImageArray as $temporaryImage) {
    if (is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/'.$temporaryImage)) {
        $images[]=array("imgSrc" => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/'.$temporaryImage);
    }
}`

4. and to prepare the useful subset of the texts as well:

`$texts = array();
foreach ($temporaryTextArray as $temporaryText) {
    if (is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].
       '/img/gallery/data/'.$temporaryText)) {
        $texts[]=array("name" => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].
       '/img/gallery/data/'.$temporaryText, "content" =>                 file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/gallery/data/'.$temporaryText));
    }
}`

5. Finally, search for matches:

`foreach ($images as $imageKey => $imageValue) {
    $imageContent = file_get_contents($imageValue["imgSrc"]);
    $images[$imageKey]["matches"] = array();
    foreach ($texts as $text) {
        if (file_get_contents($text["content"]) === $imageContent) {
            $images[$imageKey]["matches"][]=$text["name"];
        }
    }
}`

Note, that the solution does not assume that there is a match at all and if there if a match, that is unique. However, the burden of testing is left upon you, feel free to tell me if you have any problems. The intention is to have an `$images` array, which will hold arrays, having an `"imgSrc"` element and a `"matches"` element, which will hold the set of matched text file names.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start trying this out now and get back to you if I have any problems.

Comment: I don't want to sound stupid, but should `$images` contain anything with this code alone? All I'm getting is `array(0) { }`. Also, just so you know, on `file_get_contents` you've put square brackets instead of normal ones.

Comment: As I already mentioned, the code was not tested. At file_get_contents there was a square bracket indeed. It was a typo. $images should not be empty as long as your images folder contains any image. $temporaryImageArray will be an array containing the filenames of the specified path. $images is an empty array at start, but after traversing $temporaryImageArray, it should contain some elements.

Comment: I added trailing slashes to each directory and now it somewhat works. `file_get_contents` seems to be looking for the contents of the contents, but I should be ok from here.